# Content div remaining height

Tags: css, html, height

Im trying to get a layout with header, footer and two columns. 
The width of the site must be relative to the screen resolution and the height as well. 
The right column should have a width of 250px. The left column (content) should have a vertical scrollbar if the content is to large.

So with other words, the header, footer and right side should always be visible and be fixed. The content should have vertical scrollbar if needed.

Thanks

Edit:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
    font: 11px Tahoma, Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #3d5770;
    background-color: #A7A7A7;  
}   
    #wrapper
{   
    min-width: 987px;   
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 98%; 
}   
    #header
{
background-color: orange;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;   
    height:100px;
    background-color: orange;    
}   
    #main
{    
    width: 100%;
    background-color: White;
}

#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 98%;
}       

#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-right: 262px;
    background-color: White;
}

#right
{       
    width: 245px;    
    float: right; 
}

#rightInner
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 244px;
    background-color: Lime;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">         
    <div id="header">header</div>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="right">
            <div id="rightInner">Banners</div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">footer</div>         
</div>       

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the content div is growing horizontaly and the height is the max height of the screen. This works fine in my 22" screen but when I change the screensize I get a little split in my screen between the content and right div...

Comment: Do you have any code that we could look at? There are a lot of places that have examples of this - One possible link: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Comment: What's your question? What've you tried?

Comment: I think http://rentacoder.com is more appropriate for this.

Comment: Sorry for the not inserted code example. I added my sample project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution!!! I just added the left column for sample. You can delete it if you want.

**NOTE: This doesn't work in IE7!!!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font: 11px Tahoma, Arial;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: #3d5770;
            background-color: #A7A7A7;
        }
        #header, #footer, #main
        {
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 987px;
            width: 98%;
            margin-left: 1%;                        
        }
        #content, #right, #left
        {
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        #header
        {
            height: 100px;
            top: 0;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        #main
        {
            top: 100px;
            bottom: 30px;
            background-color: White;
        }        
        #footer
        {
            height: 30px;
            bottom: 0px;            
            background-color: #9933FF;
        }     
        #innerContent    
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #left
        {
            float: left;
            width: 245px;            
            margin-right: 3px; /* Space between content and left div */
            background-color: Lime;
        }
        #right
        {
            float: right;
            width: 245px;            
            margin-left: 3px; /* Space between content and right div */
            background-color: Lime;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left">Banners Banners Banners Banners Banners 54321</div>
        <div id="right">Banners Banners Banners Banners Banners 54321</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="innerContent">
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content 1
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content 2
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content Dynamic content
                Dynamic content 3                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTv5B/)

Did some different way,

```
html, body { background: #ccc; }
.wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    min-width:998px;
}

.main {
    margin: 0 220px 0 0;
}

.main, .sidebar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee; 
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @LockTar Although this is exactly your structure, you can do your own upon this.

Comment: Hi Sameera, Getting two divs side by side is not really a big deal. The problem is that I can't get it to work in combination with a content div that has the remaining height of the page...